# I need to resize the selected items in fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I can't resize these items. The `set` function is not working and is not recognizing the object collection.

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))

canvas.renderAll();

//select all items first (this works)
var objs = canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {  
     return o.set('active', true);
});

//deactivate some items i dont want to resize (this works)
canvas.item(0).set('active', false);
canvas.item(1).set('active', false);
canvas.item(2).set('active', false);
canvas.item(3).set('active', false);
canvas.item(4).set('active', false);

canvas.renderAll();
//the problem starts here 
var o = canvas.getActiveGroup();
o.set({width:100, height:100});
```

Comment: Was my answer of any help to you?  Do you need anything further?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/pnpc3j3r/.

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))

canvas.renderAll();

//select all items first (this works)
var objs = canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {
  return o.set('active', true);
});
canvas.renderAll();

//deactivate some items i dont want to resize (this works)
canvas.item(0).set('active', false);
canvas.item(1).set('active', false);
canvas.item(2).set('active', false);
canvas.item(3).set('active', false);
canvas.item(4).set('active', false);

canvas.renderAll();
//this is where the problem goes away 
canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {
  return (o.active ? o.set({
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }).setCoords() : o);
});
canvas.renderAll();
```

The reason `set` function's not working is the object is undefined, you have no active "group" - you only have objects with the active property set to true.